# UWP Write (and read) file in a (from) folder from a string

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm developing an application for UWP only for desktop. A user can select in a *Settings page* where he wants to create some files and folders. Usually I used `StreamWriter` like:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path)) {
    file.WriteLine("Something");
}
```

I tried to use now `StorageFolder`

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

but I can't find a way to specify a folder from a string like `C:\MyFolder`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want the folder to be exclusively specified from a string?

Comment: @GeorgeChond Yes. Basically the application creates some files that a user has to upload in a bank system from a specific folder. What do you suggest also? I know I could use a normal Windows App but I want to learn more about UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it not possible at the moment to avoid the interaction with the user. In my point of view this is quite odd but that's it.

Then when a user had selected a folder all application can work on that. The documentation is no very clear about how we can use all functionalities. In the following code you can find an example how to implement that. Please, if the code is wrong or I can improve it, tell me.

```
/// <summary>
/// Picks a folder.
/// </summary>
public async void PickFolder() {
    var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
    folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = 
        Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;

    // unless you want to open a folder, FileTypeFilter is required
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".cs");
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    if (folder != null) {
        // Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder
        // (including other sub-folder contents)
        Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.
            FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);

        StorageFolder mainFolder = await folder.CreateFolderAsync("Generator");
        await mainFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Code");
        await mainFolder.CreateFolderAsync("EventsArgs");

        StorageFolder newFolder = 
                  await CreateFileInANewFolder(mainFolder, "MyFolder", "MyCode.cs",
                      new List<string>() { "My code line 1", "My code line 2" });
        List<string> fileLines = await ReadFile(newFolder, "MyCode.cs");

        StorageFile file = 
            await mainFolder.CreateFileAsync("Code.cs", 
                                             CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        List<string> lines = new List<string>() { 
                 "Hello world!", "This is a second line" 
        };

        await FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(file, lines);
    }
    else {
        // the user didn't select any folder
    }
}
```

Another function receives the folder reference and creates a folder and a file.

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates the file in a new folder.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="folder">The folder.</param>
/// <param name="newFolder">The new folder.</param>
/// <param name="filename">The filename.</param>
/// <param name="lineContent">Content of the line.</param>
/// <returns>Task&lt;StorageFolder&gt;.</returns>
public async Task<StorageFolder> CreateFileInANewFolder(
    StorageFolder folder, string newFolder, string filename, List<string> lineContent) {
    StorageFolder myFolder = await folder.CreateFolderAsync(newFolder);
    StorageFile file = await myFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, 
                       CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(file, lineContent);

    return myFolder;
}
```

This function reads a file from a folder.

```
/// <summary>
/// Reads the file.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="folder">The folder.</param>
/// <param name="filename">The filename.</param>
/// <returns>Task&lt;List&lt;System.String&gt;&gt;.</returns>
public async Task<List<string>> ReadFile(StorageFolder folder, string filename) {
    StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(filename);
    IList<string> lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
    return lines.ToList();
}
```

For this you must add the following `using`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
```

When a user selected a folder with `PickFolder` this function creates a folder underneath called `Generator` and under that other two folders called `Code` and `EventsArgs`.

Then it calls `CreateFileInANewFolder`. This function has as parameter the `StorageFolder` for the selected folder and this function creates a new folder and underneath a new file.

`ReadFile` reads the file created with `CreateFileInANewFolder` and returns the lines.

I hope this example can help someone.

Answer (score 3):

You can let the user specify the folder he wants using the [FolderPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207881) class.

```
var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
if (folder != null)
{
    // Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder
    // (including other sub-folder contents)
    Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);

    //<<Here, you can write your files in the selected folder.>>

}
else
{
    //Operation cancelled.
}
```

You can find more info on how to use it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers).